# Observable.forkJoin shows a squiggly under forkJoin

Tags: angular, rxjs6

Recently i came to know about forkJoin where we could combine multiple http calls and make the code neater. But for some reason I get a red squiggly under the forkJoin part.
I have imported the observable this way

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
```

And this is how I am using forkJoin
[image]

Comment: import Observable from rxjs/Observable

Comment: what's your `rxjs` version

Comment: @ChellappanV I did that it gave me a squiggly under Observable

Comment: @Vikas rxjs v6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**RxJS 5.5 syntax**

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';  
  return Observable.forkJoin(
        this.http.get(),
        this.http.get()
    );
```

**RxJS 6 syntax**

Don't use `Observable` patching, use `forkJoin` as a function:
*`Observable.forkJoin` (RxJS 5) changes to just `forkJoin()` in RxJS 6*

```
import {forkJoin} from 'rxjs'; // change to new RxJS 6 import syntax

return forkJoin(this.http.get(),
                 this.http.get());
```

Refer **[ChangeLog](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)**

Comment: Thanks @Vikas, That worked like a charm and it reduced a lot of code.

Comment: Glad, I could help:)

Answer (score 1):

Best practice to use forkJoin (RxJS 5.5) :

```js
public getdata() {
    return this.http.get('API_URL')
      .map((res: any) => { return res.json() })
      .catch((error: any) => error);
}

public getFun() {
    return Observable.forkJoin(
      this.getRoles(),
    )
}
```